# Is a jump server necessary with Remote Desktop to Azure VM?

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

We are setting up a new Network which includes a VM in Azure.  I can connect to this via RDC.

However, our security guy wants me to access it through a second VM for security reasons.  In other words, I first connect with RDC to a "jump server" (which is just another VM in Azure) and then from there, use RDC to connect to the second server.

Is this actually adding a layer of security?  It seems to me that unless the RDC on my local machine had somehow gotten a virus or gotten hacked, that there is no benefit to the jump server.

Comment: Maybe your guys want you to place all VMs inside a virtual network?

Answer (score 0):

If its a security requirement, the best approach is deploying all your VMs inside a Virtual Network. After that, configure a Point to Site VPN connection on Azure and install the client inside your operating system.

Using that, all your connections to the VMs are done through a secure path to Azure.